# Subsetting data in pandas with complex operations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
year_week  selling_amount 
201012     43 
201112     44
-1-1       56
```

Now there is an anomaly here. One simple way of checking is if `year_week` has any entry which has size less than 6. How can we do that in pandas ?

Comment: What is the dtype of `year_week`?  Are those strings?

Comment: It is a string as of now but I would change them to `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
criterion = df['year_week'].map(lambda x: len(x)< 6)
df[criterion].index.values
```

This works if you leave the dtype as a string and then change it to an int later.

Comment: That is a very elegant solution

Comment: I'm pretty sure using `map` is slower than using `df.year_week.str.len() < 6`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.year_week.str.len() < 6` to find rows with a `year_week` whose length is less than 6.

Comment: can you also subset based on the data type ? if there are mixed type in a column ?

Comment: @SaurabhKumarKarn: You'll have to explain what you mean.  Each column has only one dtype.  You can subset based on any criterion you can apply to each item in the column.

Answer (score 0):

As Bren said, you can find the values with

```
 df.year_week.str.len() < 6
```

where df is the name of your dataframe. You can then drop those values and recast the remaining values as integers like follows:

```
 df.drop(df.year_week.str.len() < 6, inplace=True)
 df.year_week = df.year_week.astype(int)
```